# Adding same object to different nsmutablearray memory effect

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

If i allocate an object only once and i add it to 3 nsmutablearray by using addObject method.
What would actually happen ?
Would compiler create 3 copies of same object ? Or would it just create 3 references to same object without consuming same amount of memory 3 times ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: 3 References. [more characters]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are retained by the collection and not actually copied. So 3 references will be made.

Per the documentation, [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObject:) is a toll-free bridge of [`CFMutableArrayRef`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableArrayRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex), which `CFArrayInsertValueAtIndex` function specifies:

> The value is retained by theArray
>   using the retain callback provided when theArray was created.

For `NSArray`, this callback consists of calling the `retain` method of the object. Upon removal in the collection, the `release` method will be called